# Remove an input box from dropped li component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to use the drag drop functionality of html. I have a unordered list which has draggable li components.Each li components has two input box along with it.While dropping it in the other side I want to remove the input boxes and want to dispaly only the li element name.I had given class name trunc for the input boxes in the li component.I wrote the below code but it's not doing the job.

```
    function drop(ev) {
    debugger;

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    alert(data);

    var StageId = $('#newId').val();
    alert(StageId);

    var dataname1 = document.getElementById(data);

    alert(dataname1.innerText);

    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    $("#"+data).remove(".trunc");
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$("#"+data).find("input.trunc").remove();
```

`.find` will return all the `input` with class `.trunc` and `.remove()` will remove it from the `DOM`.

If you just want to hide then do `.hide()` instead of `.remove()`

Comment: That was super awesome.. Thanks a lot.. :-)